# ffmpeg - how to repeat certain frames

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I recently recorded a 1 hour talk in which at many points (about 50) the video goes blank, but the audio is still there. For example, the first instance where this happens is at time `T1= 00:01:10` and the video disappears for D1=2 seconds. I wish to do the following. Take the frame at time point T1 and keep the same frame for the next 2 seconds. In general, if at time Ti the video disappears for Di seconds, then I want to replace the video in the period Ti to Ti+Di with the frame at Ti. After this I can extract the audio from the original and use that, something which I think I can do on my own.

I searched quite a bit on the net and I am sure that I can do this in a complicated way. But since it has to be done 50 times, I was wondering if each instance could be done using one command. Then I can manually do what I want to by issuing this command 50 times. Can someone help? Thanks in advance.